# How to disable VGA

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

If i run
`lspci | grep VGA` I get below output which tells me below VGA cards are present on my computer.

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2)
>   08:02.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc ES1000 (rev 02)

The ES1000 is an onboard card which came with my machine. Do anyone know how to disable this VGA on my machine.

The reason for this request is because if I run `xrandr` I get the output as shown below:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
>   default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      1024x768       50.0* 
>      800x600        51.0     52.0     53.0
>      680x384        54.0     55.0
>      640x480        56.0
>      512x384        57.0
>      400x300        58.0
>      320x240        59.0

Which means I am not able to configure nVidia to accept smaller resolution.

Thank you.

Comment: I would check the BIOS for an option to disable the onboard GPU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disabling via BIOS option**

Some computers have a BIOS option to disable the onboard graphics.

On boot, press your BIOS key and look for a graphics option you can disable.

**Disabling via Blacklisting**

If there is no BIOS option, you'll need to blacklist the onboard graphics by putting your kernel module that is loaded for your onboard graphics into the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

ATI graphics usually load the fglrx kernel module.

N.B. if you run `lsmod` you should see what kernel modules are loaded.  This will include any graphics kernel modules.  You should see `fglrx` as being loaded for your integrated graphics.

Choose Accessories - Terminal and then type in the terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

This will open a text editor with the contents of the current blacklisted kernel modules.  Add at the end

`blacklist fglrx`

Save and reboot.

If you re-run `lsmod` then it should show that the kernel module `fglrx` is no longer being loaded.  That means your integrated graphics is now disabled.

**Setting your NVIDIA Card resolutions**

As to your NVIDIA resolutions - have you activated any hardware drivers in the Administrator - Additional Hardware drivers window?

You'll need to run nvidia-settings to adjust your resolution when the driver is installed.

Type in the terminal

```
gksudo nvidia-settings
```

Comment: I have just rebooted my machine and checked the BIOS settings. No options available to graphics. nVidia driver is installed via Additional Drivers. How do you run nVidia-settings.

Comment: Do you know how I can locate a kernel module for a specific device?!

Comment: @bitmap - have updated - hope this helps

Comment: You are a star.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux for acpi_call.